# Embedded database to distribute with an open source webapp

Tags: open-source, database, sqlite

I'm looking to build an open source website project that will require a small database backend. I'm leaning towards using SQLite since the website will be simple, low traffic, and the users of the website will only be reading. Only the site admin will be updating.

I wonder though, sharing a SQLite file on GitHub, is that the best way? It's kind of hard to easily view the data. Is there a better data store solution for open source projects? Is it best to just include the data in a second format, like CSV, alongside the database?

Comment: How many times per day will the database be read?

Comment: What web server software are you planning to use?

Comment: Are you saying you want to distribute the stored data along with your source code? Why? How does that make sense if the data is changing (you said admins will be changing the data in the database)?

Comment: What does small, smoke, and low-traffic mean to you? Get more specific if you want helpful Answers.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I would estimate maybe 50 reads a day.  At this time, running on IIS.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was considering distributing the data with the code, yes.  That's kind of the reason for the question.  A big binary file might not be the most friendly approach.  Changes may only happen a few times a week, but still, that might not be very attractive.

Comment: " It's kind of hard to easily view the data" - no it's not; just ask us how ;-)  And, yup, I would go with SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several open source webapps (namely Alfresco and Liferay) distribute a small amount of data with the webapp, to make it easy to get started with. A beginner can just run the start script, and the webapp is up and running already with sample data.

Here is how they do:

1. Write a standard SQL script that creates the data.
2. Write some code that creates an empty [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) and loads the SQL from step 1 into it.
3. Commit both the SQL script and the code into GitHub.
4. When a webmaster downloads the webapp and runs it, the first time it will create the database. The webmaster can then add more data.

Please note that the HyperSQL database has a memory cache, so each read does not mean a disk read access. Each write means a disk write access, though.

Comment: I like this, keep things as readable as possible, than compile them on first run.  I'll dig more into this idea.

Comment: I opted for SQLite.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but it seems your goal is to distribute a relatively fresh copy of your database’s data alongside the source code of your app that accesses that database. But you do not explain your motivation or goal. I imagine you either want machines to read that data, or you want people to read that data.

Either way, consider distributing the data separately from the source code. Combining them is unusual and seems confusing to me.

## Machine-readable

If your goal is convenience in establishing an instance of the database for the programmer using your source code to build and deploy for themselves, then you should include the database’s data files.

You could do this win SQLite. But beware that SQLite is indeed quite “lite”, meant more as a slightly better alternative to writing files, it is not meant to be a serious database. You have not stated the size and shape of your data, so I cannot advise if SQLite fits your needs or not.

A more serious database you might consider is the [*H2 Database Engine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). It is written in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), and so requires a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). H2 stores data to a single file that your could easily copy. H2 can run embedded within an app, or can be run separately as a database server.

## Human-readable

If your goal is simply to let people peruse a recent copy of the data, then you need to export the data from the database to a human-readable text format.

If the goal is simply perusing, then write out web pages using basic [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) using the [`table`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) tag. And perhaps a bit of [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). Use the programming language of your app to generate these text files.

If you want the user to make use of the data such as opening in a spreadsheet, then use a common format such as [Tab-delimited (TSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) or [Comma-separated Values (CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). You might want to use a library to assist in the writing of such files, like [*Apache Commons CSV*](http://commons.apache.org/csv/) in Java (which also writes TSV).

You will likely want to write out one file for each table in your database. Beware of memory limits in web browsers and spreadsheet apps; you may need to break a very large table into multiple files.